# Issue with download from Azure with ClientID , TennantID and ClientSecret

Tags: java, azure

I am trying to download blob from Azure storage from java code m by using  ClientID , TennantID and ClientSecret

Here is code for obtaining client :

```
private BlobContainerClient getContainerClient_SP(String containerName) {
    ClientSecretCredential clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredentialBuilder()
            .tenantId(tenantId)
            .clientId(clientId)
            .clientSecret(clientSecret)
            .build();

    String endpoint = String.format(Locale.ROOT, "https://%s.blob.core.windows.net/%s", accountName, containerName);
    BlobContainerClient containerClient = new BlobContainerClientBuilder()
            .endpoint(endpoint)
            .credential(clientSecretCredential)
            .buildClient();

    return containerClient;

}
```

Here is code snippet for download :

```
try {
    BlobContainerClient containerClient = getContainerClient_SP(containerName);
    BlobClient blobClient = containerClient.getBlobClient(blobName);        
    String destinationPath = "C:\\MyFolder\\MyFileName";
    blobClient.downloadToFile(destinationPath,true); //Exception thrown here 
    System.out.println("Download OK");
}
catch (Exception ex) {
    System.out.println("APP exception: "+ex.getMessage());
    throw ex;
}
```

Exception is :

```
    Exception in thread "main" 
com.azure.storage.blob.models.BlobStorageException: If you are using a StorageSharedKeyCredential, and the server returned an error message that says 'Signature did not match', you can compare the string to sign with the one generated by the SDK. To log the string to sign, pass in the context key value pair 'Azure-Storage-Log-String-To-Sign': true to the appropriate method call.
    If you are using a SAS token, and the server returned an error message that says 'Signature did not match', you can compare the string to sign with the one generated by the SDK. To log the string to sign, pass in the context key value pair 'Azure-Storage-Log-String-To-Sign': true to the appropriate generateSas method call.
    Please remember to disable 'Azure-Storage-Log-String-To-Sign' before going to production as this string can potentially contain PII.
    Status code 403, "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Error><Code>AuthorizationPermissionMismatch</Code><Message>This request is not authorized to perform this operation using this permission.
    RequestId:57625f26-801e-0036-206a-ec1d2e000000
    Time:2023-09-21T09:07:08.3082584Z</Message></Error>"
        at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle.invokeWithArguments(MethodHandle.java:627)
        at com.azure.core.implementation.http.rest.ResponseExceptionConstructorCache.invoke(ResponseExceptionConstructorCache.java:56)
```

The question : Is there something missing / wrong in code or it is ONLY permission issue ?
Thanks in advance
Roles defined : [image]

Comment: Have you assigned Azure RBAC roles to that application? It would need for example Storage Blob Data Reader role.

Comment: You can do that through Portal or through Bicep/ARM/Terraform templates or command line.

Comment: Hi, @Im Go to azure portal -> subscription -> Access control(IAM)  -> Add -> Add Role assignments -> select the azure storage blob reader role -> select members (Your Application) -> click review + assign.

Comment: Added screenshot for roles defined , Is 
"Storage Blob Data Reader"  different from azure "storage blob reader role" ?

Comment: Yes, it is different for blob storage level you need to assign  `Storage Blob Data Reader` role.

Comment: Hi @Im. You need to assign the role for Azure AD application like https://i.imgur.com/jXCvo1u.png not for the user because you are authenticating by clientsecretcredential.

Answer (score 1):

Initially, I tried in my environment and got the same error.

[image]

> The question : Is there something missing / wrong in code or it is ONLY permission issue ?

I agree with Junna's comment After assigning **`Storage blob data reader`** role to my application. I can able to download the file.

**Portal:**
[image]

**Code:**

```
import com.azure.core.credential.TokenCredential;
import com.azure.identity.ClientSecretCredentialBuilder;
import com.azure.storage.blob.BlobClient;
import com.azure.storage.blob.BlobContainerClient;
import com.azure.storage.blob.BlobContainerClientBuilder;

import java.util.Locale;

public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Set the values for your Azure Blob Storage account
        String accountName = "venkat123";
        String containerName = "test1";
        String blobName = "file2.txt";
        String tenantId = "xxxx";
        String clientId = "xxxxx";
        String clientSecret = "xxxxx";

        // Create a token credential using the client secret
        TokenCredential credential = new ClientSecretCredentialBuilder()
                .tenantId(tenantId)
                .clientId(clientId)
                .clientSecret(clientSecret)
                .build();

        // Create a BlobContainerClient using the token credential
        String endpoint = String.format(Locale.ROOT, "https://%s.blob.core.windows.net", accountName);
        BlobContainerClient containerClient = new BlobContainerClientBuilder()
                .endpoint(endpoint)
                .credential(credential)
                .containerName(containerName)
                .buildClient();

        // Download the blob to a file
        String destinationPath = "C:\\Users\\xxx\\xxx\\Documents\\xx\\sample.txt";
            BlobClient blobClient = containerClient.getBlobClient(blobName);
            blobClient.downloadToFile(destinationPath, true);
            System.out.println("Download OK");
    }
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

**File:**

[image]